# I have been having trouble with setting up a Navigation drawer in the mainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, main-activity

How do you set up the Navigation Drawer in the mainActivity.java using android. I've been having trouble with it because I'm still fairly new to programming and I am attempting to make and finish my first app. I am currently stuck on the mainActivity.java because I just keep on running into more and more errors. Please help!!

Comment: Can't help you unless you give us the actual error you are getting and some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because i cant help you with out any error message or code you i recommended you to see this post here http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ it can be helpful for you or this one https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer

Comment: Those links are proving to be very helpful especially the android hive one. Thank you again. You've been a massive help! :D